# Setting a Digit Limit on a Javascript Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm trying to add functionality to my calculator that limits the amount of digits you can enter on the screen at one time. (In this case, 8, to prevent the calculator from expanding and looking ugly). I'm doing this by using 'if' statements to check if the variable representing the digits on the screen has a length longer or equal to 8, and then attempting to clear the screen if it does. At the moment, the calculator clears itself after attempting to enter two digits on the screen. Something tells me there is some integer/string conflict preventing me from achieving this task. What other solutions are there to this?

Thank you

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>My Calculator</title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="calculator">
                <div id="screen">
                        <div id="displayedVal">0</div>
                </div>
                            <div id="button-set">
                                <div>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="seven">7</button>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="eight">8</button>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="nine">9</button>
                                    <button class="operatorCalc" id="divide">÷</button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="four">4</button>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="five">5</button>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="six">6</button>
                                    <button class="operatorCalc" id="multiply">×</button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="one">1</button>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="two">2</button>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="three">3</button>
                                    <button class="operatorCalc" id="minus">-</button>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <button class="numberCalc" id="zero">0</button>
                                    <button class="operatorCalc" id="point">.</button>
                                    <button class="operatorCalc" id="plus">+</button>
                                    <button class="operatorCalc" id="equals">=</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <style>
    
                .flex-container {
                    display: flex;
                    height: 610px;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                } 
        
                .calculator {
                    background-color: #28283e; 
                    padding: 30px;
                    border-radius: 20px;
                    box-shadow: 2px 0 2px 1px;
                    height: 350px;
                }
                
                #screen {
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                    height: 70px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    margin-top: -12px;
                }
    
                #displayedVal {
                    font-size: 45px;
                    text-align: right;
                    margin-right: 5px;
                }
    
                #button-set {
                    margin-top: 16px;
                    margin-bottom: -20px;
                }
        
                button {
                    margin: 10px 5px;
                    width: 40px;
                    height: 40px;
                    border-radius: 20px;
                }
        
            </style>
    
        <script>
        
            // grabbing the digit on the screen
            var displayedNum = document.getElementById("displayedVal");
    
            // grabbing the calculator buttons
            var seven = document.getElementById("seven");
            var eight = document.getElementById("eight");
            var nine = document.getElementById("nine");
            var divide = document.getElementById("divide");
            var four = document.getElementById("four");
            var five = document.getElementById("five");
            var six = document.getElementById("six");
            var multiply = document.getElementById("multiply");
            var one = document.getElementById("one");
            var two = document.getElementById("two");
            var three = document.getElementById("three");
            var minus = document.getElementById("minus");
            var zero = document.getElementById("zero");
            var point = document.getElementById("point");
            var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
            var equals = document.getElementById("equals");
    
            var defaultVal = "0";
            var pendingVal;
            evalStringArray = []; 
            
            // separating the number buttons from the operator buttons
            var numberCalc = document.getElementsByClassName("numberCalc");
            var operatorCalc = document.getElementsByClassName("operatorCalc");
            
            // when a number button is clicked, the screen will display the number corresponding to that button
            var updateDisplayValue = (clickObj) => {
                var valOutput = clickObj.target.innerText;
    
                if (defaultVal === "0")
                    defaultVal = "";
    
                    // currentVal = "" + whichever number is pressed (string format)
                    currentVal = defaultVal + valOutput;
                    // what displays on the screen
                    displayedVal.innerText = currentVal;
                
                var numOfDigits = displayedVal.innerText.length();
                if (numOfDigits.length >= "8") 
                clearDigits();
            }
    
            function clearDigits() {
                displayedVal.innerText.clear();
            }
    
            var activateOperator = (clickObj) => {
                operatorOutput = clickObj.target.innerText;
                
                switch(operatorOutput) {
                    case divide:
                        displayedVal.innerText = valOutput / valOutput
                        break;
                    case multiply:
                        displayedVal.innerText = valOutput * valOutput
                        break;
                    case minus:
                        displayedVal.innerText = valOutput - valOutput
                        break;
                    case point:
                        break;
                    case plus:
                        displayedVal.innerText = valOutput + valOutput
                        break;
                    case equals:
                        break;
                    default: 
                }
            }
    
            // iterating through each number
            for (let i = 0; i < numberCalc.length; i++) {
                numberCalc[i].addEventListener("click", updateDisplayValue);
            }
    
            // iterating through each operator
            for (let i = 0; i < operatorCalc.length; i++) {
                operatorCalc[i].addEventListener("click", activateOperator);
            }
            
        </script>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Actually, at the moment, the calculator crashes when you click any number.

Comment: Hmmm... This is strange. I've checked mine and it lets you enter any number and that number changes if you enter another number. I've given out the full code so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: You have a number of problems, most of which can be seen in the javascript console.  For starters, ```.length``` is a property, not a function, so no ```()``` on it.

Comment: I can't see any of these errors on my console. Ah of course, didn't notice that, thanks!

Comment: Would a 'for loop' possibly be a better solution instead of an 'if' statement?